# Is it the right query on what I am looking for in openFDA?

Tags: api, data.gov, openfda, json

I have performed a query. I was planning to get the adverse report based on medicine name and age. So I did this

> https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=patient.drug.openfda.brand_name:advil+AND+patient.patientonsetage:64&limit=5

I just want to know that whether I have written the right query or not. Please help me in this case. I have gone through the JSON data. I was convinced that the data was right. But I want to make sure from openFDA people or the others who are using openFDA API like me.

Comment: it might be easier to [download the whole data set to your computer](http://www.asdfree.com/search/label/fda%20adverse%20event%20reporting%20system%20%28faers%29) and just work with it there.

Comment: Now it makes sense to me. It seems like I cannot further proceed your query because I have to proceed the same query based on gender.

Comment: May I know why it was downvoted? I'll try to rewrite in different way. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that API query looks correct but note the following:

- You can get a count of the adverse event reactions through the API by adding `&count=..` to the end of your URL like this: https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=patient.drug.openfda.brand_name:advil+AND+patient.patientonsetage:64&count=patient.reaction.reactionmeddrapt.exact
- You should be aware that 45% (1,734,133 of the 3,814,280) adverse events on openFDA as of right now do not have any age set. You can see this at [https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=*missing*:patient.patientonsetage](https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=_missing_:patient.patientonsetage) for openFDA in general and at [https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=*missing*:patient.patientonsetage%20AND%20patient.drug.openfda.brand_name:advil](https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=_missing_:patient.patientonsetage%20AND%20patient.drug.openfda.brand_name:advil) for  your `advil` query
- Age is not always (but usually is) denoted in years by openFDA

Comment: I appreciate your help. It seems like my query and your query(regarding count or limit in first point of yours) are very similar. But the JSON data is drastically changed. May I know what it made changed? Which one is more appropriate to find the adverse reports based on medicine name and age. In my query I can get directly total number of adverse reports in total field(total=414 for the query I mentioned).

Comment: @Mike - what changed in my first bullet point is that I added `&count` which will have the API do a count on the field specified (in this case `patient.reaction.reactionmeddrapt.exact`). This is useful and should save you time if all you want is the count of adverse event reactions for the query.If you want to go through all 414 results and count the adverse event reactions and other things such as sex and weight, then you should omit the `&count=..`. Does this make sense?